# Xamarin.Forms BackgroudImage not showing

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to apply background image to all pages within my Xamarin.Forms app using an application style, but it is not applying the style to the pages.

I tried with this:

App.xaml resources

```
...
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="Page">
      <Setter Property="BackgroundImageSource" Value="logo.png"/>
    </Style>
...
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="FinansovoPregledi.MainPage">
    <StackLayout Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Button Text="Login" BackgroundColor="#006BE6" x:Name="scanButton" TextColor="WhiteSmoke" Command="{Binding LogInCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = loginViewModel;

        }
...
```

This isn't working. In my scenario the background image has a white background with transparency.

Comment: Where is this style being applied? What does the page xaml look like, what's it's type, are there any styles being applied at that level? Is the image showing up on some platforms, but not others? You can check to see if you have your image resource setup properly by adding just the image to one of your pages.

Comment: I add the style in App.xaml . Image is saved in Resources

Comment: I figured as much. I think it'd be best to update your question to include larger snippets of your code though. It's hard to see what the problem is when the code in the question is incomplete.

Comment: i changed this is my all code

Comment: Did you try to set the `BackgroundImageSource` on the `ContentPage` directly? Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ContentPage is derived from Page and for your style to apply to Pages as well as all controls derived from Pages you need to set the [ApplyToDerivedTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.style.applytoderivedtypes?view=xamarin-forms) property of your style to True.

Your style would need to be

```xml
<Style ApplyToDerivedTypes="True" TargetType="Page">
  <Setter Property="BackgroundImageSource" Value="logo.png"/>
</Style>
```

Another approach would be to set the TargetType to ContentPage

```xml
<Style TargetType="ContentPage">
  <Setter Property="BackgroundImageSource" Value="logo.png"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Now its working on Content Pages. But when i have MasterDetailPage in Detail Page i can't see the BackgroudImage

Comment: What type of page is being set to the detail page? Also, which approach did you use?
Also feel free to up vote and select my answer since you say it is working.

Comment: I'd also suggest rethinking your UI's company branding. It's ill advised to put a logo on every single page. You can probably engage in a very thorough discussion over at https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Its a backgroud image and  its transparent just a little visible

Comment: IN master detail is also ContentPages

Comment: I'm confused on the "IN master detail is also ContentPages" comment. Are you having trouble with the MasterDetailPage.Master part or the MasterDetailPage.Details part?

Comment: It is but maybe because i got CollectionView not showing